# Force-Printing Partial pages in page oriented printer

Tags: printing, ms-dos

How can I force a page-oriented printer to print a partial page?

From a command prompt (In Windows XP, but true since MS-DOS days), if you direct output to a page oriented printer such as a Laserjet, the printer won't start printing until either (1) the page buffer is full, or (2) some type of form-feed command is sent.

In my case, I am working with some old DOS programs for which there is (IMO) no good modern version. I'm working from a command window in XP and printing to an HP DeskJet 9650 printer.
If I try to print a directory (or any redirected text) that is longer than one printed page, the first page will print but the second page is stuck in the printer's buffer.
If I try to print text that is shorter than one page I get nothing.
If I send more text to it, the page will eventually print, but then I still have text left in the buffer.

If I go to XP and use NotePad to send a file, the printer will print the page containing the buffered text, then print a new page with the Notepad file.

So somewhere there is a control character that says "This is the end of the text - now print it."  What is that command?

I have tried ^L and ^Z with no success.

I recall from many years that there was a solution to this (For the LaserJet), but I no longer recall it and can't find it in any notes.

Comment: I put a top of page character in a batch file called TOP.  I just ran TOP when a page was stuck

Comment: I have found that if I open a text editor and insert a ^L, then print it, it prints the buffer and ejects the page.  If I save that as a text file and print the file, it also works. It also ejects a second page.

If I create a text file containing only a space and save it, the printing it will print the buffer and eject the page without a second page. 

But for some reason, I can't send a ^L from the command prompt that works.

Oh, well, I guess I can to a "Print page" command about as easily.

Your reply put me on the track.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Force-Printing Partial pages in page oriented printer

I have done this a long time ago.

Put a Form Feed in a batch file and call it TOP  (.bat)

Then run TOP when a page is stuck.  That worked well for me.